# floating element beside jquery's tabs not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div that floating on the left of `jquery's` tabs.

This is the floating element's css :

```
#twitter{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

This is the html structure :

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="<? echo base_url();?>image/header.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="twitter"> 
        <h1>TWITER</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#book">All About Love</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id="home">
        <p><?php echo $home; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
        <p><?php echo 'Gallery'; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <?php echo $about; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="book"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is what i get from the code above :

[image]

What should i do to make the div (`#twitter`) floating left **outside** the tabs?

**EDIT**

This is what happened after i added float:left to the tabs :

[image]

Thanks :D

Comment: Make the tab div also float:left

Comment: Please see my updated qusetion

Comment: Looks like a float drop. So probably the width of `#twitter` + the width of `#tabs` exceeds the width of the body. You haven't provided all the CSS, so it's hard to say for sure. I've copied the code you provided exactly into a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6K7Wt/ ... and just added `float:left` to `#tabs`, and the layout works.

Comment: @Faust Thanks for your help. Yes, its working when the content is small. I have a fairly big content, do you have any suggestion? How about if i count the width manually with %?

Comment: You can place a min-width on the body equal or greater than sum of the widths of #twitter and #tabs (plus their margins, borders, and paddings). If the browser viewport's width is less than this, then depending on the body's `overflow` property, either the viewport will provide a horizontal scrollbar (`overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`) or the tabs will be visually cropped (`overflow:hidden`). Alternatively, you could wrap these elements in a div and apply `min-width` to that element instead of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you float the tabs (#tabs) left, that should be enough.